# Stuck on a palindrome iteration

Tags: javascript

I personally cannot figure out why this function works the way it does. The value of variable "i" is per each iteration right? So wouldn't the "i" in the "str[str.length-i-1]" means to skip out one of the elements of the array made by split after subtracting from the length and then 1?

For example, of how I envision it, once the second iteration comes in, wouldn't it be: "racecar[7-2-1]" since i is 2? Then it would be racecar[4] right? However, racecar is a palindrome so it does return true; many challenge videos does not explain why the "i" is working as such. Any experienced help would be appreciated!

```
function palindrome2(str){
    return str.split('').every((char, i)=> {
        console.log(i)
        return char === str[str.length-i-1]
    });
}

console.log(palindrome2("racecar"))
```

Comment: To add to this, I know I am definitely WRONG but I can't seem to find an explanation why I am wrong haha

Comment: Why not just print it out and see? Or check in the debugger? On the second iteration, `i == 1`, btw. JS is zero-indexed arrays.

Comment: I tried printing i and it printed 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. I just do not understand the arithmetic  where str[str.length-i-1]. Why would this make any sense when it is saying on the 3rd iteration it is saying "hey time to minus the length with 2 and also subtract 1"? am I not getting this correctly?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it :) You're comparing the current character with the character across the "middle".

Answer (score 1):

Oh I got it! I took it out step by step and now it makes more sense! The console log of "i" confused me even more.. So i just replaced everything I can after every iteration. Every letter matches each index it is iterating over! WOo hoo

```
function palindrome2(str){
    return str.split('').every((r, 0)=> {
        return r === racecar[7-0-1]
    });

}function palindrome2(str){
    return str.split('').every((a, 1)=> {
        return a === racecar[7-1-1]
    });
}

}function palindrome2(str){
    return str.split('').every((c, 2)=> {
        return c === racecar[7-2-1]
    });
}
```

Comment: I would have done it on paper and/or just printed out the result of the math--but this is the quickest way to understanding: play computer. Good work, and good perseverance.